# iPhone 6 Plus changes selected view in More, when rotating to landscape and back to portrait

Tags: ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

On an iPhone 6 Plus when a user selects the second-to-last view in the More tab, then rotates the device to landscape and back to portrait, the visible view controller will change to another.

I've been experiencing this issue since the 6 Plus came out.  It's reproducible with iOS Xcode 6/iOS 8 and Xcode 7/iOS 9 Beta 5

I built a sample application with the TabBar fully configured in IB.
https://github.com/kselman/iPhone6PlusTabBar/tree/master

**Edit:**
How do I prevent the UITabBar from interrupting and changing the view after rotating?

Comment: What's the question? File a bug report.

Comment: BTW I can easily reproduce completely independently.

Comment: Thanks for confirming it.  I filed a bug July 18th 2015, and so far no updates from Apple.  On this particular ViewController I allow the user to record/manage greetings videos. So rotating to landscape and back to portrait is very likely for me.